# Тире вместо слова "что" в сложном предложении

Tags: тире

Верно ли употреблено тире в следующем предложении?

*Сергей Николаевич лишь иногда интересовался у него местом и временем своего нахождения, видать, боялся добрый человек - не свою жизнь он живёт, не тогда родился и, возможно, от этого страдает.*

Comment: Союз "что" при бессоюзной связи между частями предложения я бы заменил на двоеточие. 
Обычно двоеточие либо разъясняет, то, о чем говорилось ранее, либо поясняет.

Answer (score 3):

Предлагается **редактирование** (дискуссионный вариант):

*Сергей Николаевич лишь иногда интересовался у него местом и временем своего нахождения: видать, **боялся** добрый человек — **не свою жизнь он живёт, не тогда родился** — и от этого, возможно, **страдал**.*

Но это надо **обсудить** (много изменений).

Comment: Спасибо, Sharon. Это интересный вариант. С первым тире всё ясно. Может быть, кто-нибудь ещё подключится для обсуждения второго. С удовольствием восприму такую информацию к размышлению.